# How can i make my iOS 16.2 realize my Lightning adapter is hooked up to something else and not headphones?

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones, lightning

I mistakenly hit that my cars AUX was headphones and now my AUX is basically unusable. The music just sounds so bad but I haven’t gotten the question again when I connect and I can’t find it in Setting anywhere.

Does anyone know if this is something I can fix?

Comment: Headphohnes as opposed to... what?

Comment: Try this: Disable Access to USB accessories when locked.   *Settings -> Face ID & Passcode -> Turn Off USB Accessories*. Then wait an hour or so, then connect it.  It should re-learn the connection and ask permission to connect.

Comment: @MarcWilson, you can plug in the lightning to USB adapter and connect things like USB drives, a camera, SD card….it’s not limited to headphones.

Comment: @MarcWilson as opposed to speakers / car head unit / etc.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and it’s so so frustrating, did you end up working out how to fix it??